# Hibernate @CollectionOfElements Annotation for internationalisation

Tags: java, hibernate, internationalization, annotations

Does anyone know of a good example (on the net) of how to use the @collectrionOfElements annotations in Hibernate. I have existing model objects and I need to internationalize a few fields on each of them ie: Name, Description . . .

Does this mean I do not have to change/add new tables and model objects as Hibernate will know how to create these on the fly?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it going to work

http://i-proving.com/2006/11/06/collection-of-elements/